# RecyclerView Bugs?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, recyclerview-layout

I have a Note-App. In the Main Activity the Notes are going to be listed with a `RecyclerView`. To apply changes in the database I use `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`.
But I have a big problem. First, everything works fine. When the ListItems are changed once or more than one time everything gets confusing. 
Then these things happen:

1. RecyclerViewItems are invisible (https://www.dropbox.com/s/76e0pi3bgmqdk4u/empty_list.mp4?dl=0)
2. RecyclerViewItem doesn't show
   (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ai92ypev1509qg/dont_show.mp4?dl=0)
3. RecyclerViewItem doesn't remove (https://www.dropbox.com/s/3k2k3ryecfwnqil/dosnt_remove.mp4?dl=0)

In the Videos, you can see all Items will work correctly after you scroll in the recycler view. I don't know why? Maybe the recyclerview than gets really reloaded?

Here is how I set up the RecyclerView and when I call the Adapter(Snippet of MainActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {

private FirebaseFirestore db;
public NoteListAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;

private ListenerRegistration firestoreListener;
private RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNoteList);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    setUpRecyclerView();
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(true).build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    Query query = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes");


    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>().setQuery(query, Note.class).build();
    adapter = new NoteListAdapter(response, MainActivity.this);

    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CustomRecyclerViewDivider(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, MainActivity.this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    adapter.checkIflayoutMustImprove();
}


@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {
    adapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

private void deleteNote(String id) {
    db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes")
            .document(id)
            .delete()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(NOTE_DELETED_EVENT, null);
                }
            });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}}
```

Here is the ItemRecyclerTouchHelper:

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        final View foregroundView = ((NoteViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((NoteViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final View foregroundView = ((NoteViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                        int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((NoteViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;

    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}}
```

I am sitting at this problem for two weeks and I really need help. I hope anyone can help me. I even don't know what the problem is. Is the problem the RecyclerView or Firebase or a simple bug? When you need any other files let me know.
Thanks for helping me.

*Edit NoteListAdapter*

public class NoteListAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter{

```
private Context context;
private RelativeLayout no_data_layout;
private Animation fadeIn, fadeOut;

public NoteListAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options, @NonNull Context context) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Note note) {
    holder.bind(context, note, getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId(), note.getNote_image_url());

    checkIflayoutMustImprove();

    //setAlarms
    if (note.getRemindeDate() != null) {
        if (note.getRemindeDate().before(new Date())) {
            note.setRemindeDate(null);
        }
        if (note.getRemindeDate() != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, TodoNotificationService.class);
            i.putExtra(TodoNotificationService.TODOUUID, note.getId());
            i.putExtra(TodoNotificationService.TODOTEXT, note.getTitle());
            i.putExtra(TodoNotificationService.TODOCONTENT, note.getContent());
            MainActivity.createAlarm(context, i, getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId().hashCode(), note.getRemindeDate().getTime());
        }
    }
    if (note.getRemindeDate() == null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, TodoNotificationService.class);
        int id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId().hashCode();
        MainActivity.deleteAlarm(context, i, id);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getSnapshots().size();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note_view, parent, false);
    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    notifyItemRemoved(position);

    checkIflayoutMustImprove();
}}
```

Comment: you really shouldn't be calling any 'notifyItemRemoved' or 'notifyDatasetChanged' methods, all you should do is: Listen to the FireStore, and Update the FireStore. The FirebaseUI library should take care of the rest for you

Comment: @Linxy But what should I do? As it seems it doesn't work. I don't think that it would be better to remove all `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks for all your help, but no one couldn't answer this. I coded an immersiveMode() in my App. He sets the screen to fullscreen even with any interactions. I noticed that all bugs I ever had with recyclerview were gone as I removed the immersiveMode() methods. I couldn't say why, but now it works. But thanks to everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

inside your

```
addOnCompleteListener()
```

so your onCompleteListener will look like this

```
addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(NOTE_DELETED_EVENT, null);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

if that doesn't work than you should publish you adapter class also.

Comment: Thanks. It makes it works longer. But after a while adding and deleting items it doesn't work again. What do you mean with 'publish your adapter class also'? Can you give me an example pls?

Comment: What do you mean it makes it work longer? 
The issue was that your call to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` runs before `onCompleteListener` has finished (`onCompleteListener` runs asynchronously).

I mean you need to publish `NoteListAdapter.class`

Comment: @Mina..Hey thank you. I posted my Adapter in my Question. So it works for a time. But after a while I have the same problems. And what isnt fixed is the iusse when I add an Item the list only gets update when i scroll in recycler view. (Note: I add a note into firestore and firestorequerylistener should update this in mainactivity automaticly)

Comment: Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you are adding an item? And where is you code for adding a new item?

Comment: I don't call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. I add it only to firestore. this will happen in a separate activity.