# Bug with the recycle view and the viewholder adapater in Android

Tags: java, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I am getting a very strange bug in my application. To make it more clear I will create a similar example with minus code.

I am reading objects from **Firebase Realtime Database** with an `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. While I am reading the objects, I am stored them in an Array that I passed to an **Adapter** in a **Recycleview**. At this point, I can say, after debugging, that all seems to work correctly.

Then in the Adapter, I have a code similar to this:

```
public class AdapterObject extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterObject.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Object> objectList;
    Context mContext;

    public AdapterObject (Context context, ArrayList<Object> objectList){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.objectList = objectList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterObject.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.object_grid_layout, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterObject.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object o = objectList.get(position);
        Log.d("TAG", o.getAtribute());
        if (o.getAtribute().equals("A")){
            holder.atribute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objectList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView atribute;

        boolean favorite;
        String descuento, precioOriginal;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            atribute = itemView.findViewById(R.id.atribute);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code if the current object has the **attribute value == "A"**, then his **Textview** is displayed, otherwise, the **Textview** remains hidden.

All seems correct when I debug it because the objects and their attribute corresponds to the Database, but when I deploy the application in the Android simulator and I start going up and down on the **Recycleview**, the holders start to display the **Textviews** although the console debugs seems correct...

Is this normal in RecycleViews? How can I fix that? I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553633/16051479), do you think it has any relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extract from the [RecyclerView documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

> As the name implies, RecyclerView recycles those individual elements.
> When an item scrolls off the screen, RecyclerView doesn't destroy its
> view. Instead, RecyclerView reuses the view for new items that have
> scrolled onscreen. This reuse vastly improves performance, improving
> your app's responsiveness and reducing power consumption.

That means that when the view gets reused it will keep the current properties. It's up to you to change them when `onBindViewHolder` gets called.

In your specific case

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterObject.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object o = objectList.get(position);
    Log.d("TAG", o.getAtribute());
    if (o.getAtribute().equals("A")){
        holder.atribute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else. {
        holder.atribute.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
```